# How do I split viewport and place a different empty image in each one?

Tags: objects, interface, workspaces

How do I split viewport and place a different empty image in each one? As of now, when I place the empty in one view it appears in the other.

[image]

Comment: Usually, you use different images for different views. For example, if you look from the front,  you will not see images that's rotated 90 deg to the view. If you don't want to see the image from back, you can toggle visibility from back in image settings.

Comment: here is what I did step by step, 1) split the view screen  2) dragged image (empty) into the left side ----- at that point, the image was placed into the right side also. My question is why?  And thanks for the response.

Comment: reference images now are presented as objects in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

first step is to to place each of your ref images into different collections and your objects into a seperate collection

[image]

Now press 'N' on your keypad and go to the 'View panel'

[image]

go to the collection section and check the 'local collections' option

[image]

**Now just repeat the same steps in the other section of your splitted viewport**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just follow this GIF step by step.
Hope this Helps

**By the way please remeber to place each of your ref images into different collections and your objects into a seperate collection and you can view the panel by pressing *N* on your keypad**

Comment: No, that is not what I am looking for. I will do a screen record. I think that will show what I mean much better than I can explain in words.

Comment: oh ok sorry for that

Comment: made a video, without sound, for now, too much noise here right now.... hopefully, you can understand what I mean. If not I will do another with audio. Here is the link, https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C-fZ5c9wqcHaRgZF8nFg-BiJhkNLaOyq

Comment: crf, you need to give access to everyone so they can view the video because you have provided us with a google drive link.Right now I am unable to play the video

Comment: right click on it and select preview

Comment: should  work now, first time .... sorry

Comment: ok.... but it still doesn`t work

Comment: just clicked on your notification and changed to everyone with link, try it now.

Comment: Now I have access to watch the video,thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130288/discussion-between-ribbit12-and-crf).