# hiding one image only in one of the two viewports

Tags: image

I did a vertical split screen. I've got two viewports now. And I loaded two perpendicular images.

I wished to hide one image only in the first viewport and make it visible in the second viewport, but it kept disappearing in both viewports at once.

How do I make one image visible in the first viewport and invisible in the second viewport at the same time?

Comment: Hello and welcome, you mean reference images?

Comment: The same question was asked a month ago https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239980/how-do-i-split-viewport-and-place-a-different-empty-image-in-each-one/239987#239987

Answer (score 1):

**The first step is to place each of your ref images into different collections and your objects into a separate collection**

[image]

**Now press 'N' on your keypad and go to the 'View panel'**

[image]

**go to the collection section and check the 'local collections' option and press the eye icon near the reference image or objects name to disable and enable it in one of the split viewport.**

[image]

**Now just repeat the same steps in the other section of your split viewport**

[image]

** I added  a GIF so you can get a better understanding**

[image]

Comment: That's better... I hope I don't get downvoted now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is local view. In one window select the image that's supposed to be visible, plus the objects belonging to it and hit numpad / to toggle local view. It's a bit inflexible when you want to add new objects, you'll have to repeat the process.

A more flexible approach would be checking these options:
[image]
If they get you there, this is preferable, but the options are a bit limited.